# How an R function can be used before being defined

Tags: r, shiny

I came across this spinet of code where the function `rval_top_ingredients()` was used to render a D3wordcloud **before** it was defined. I think that would throw an error in case of Python as the script is executed from top to bottom. Why did it work in R then? Thankyou.

```
output$wc_ingredients <- d3wordcloud::renderD3wordcloud({
     ingredients_df <- rval_top_ingredients()
     d3wordcloud(ingredients_df$ingredient, ingredients_df$nb_recipes, tooltip = TRUE)
  })

  rval_top_ingredients <- reactive({
    recipes_enriched %>% 
      filter(cuisine == input$cuisine) %>% 
      arrange(desc(tf_idf)) %>% 
      head(input$nb_ingredients) %>% 
      mutate(ingredient = forcats::fct_reorder(ingredient, tf_idf))
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R doesn’t differ from Python here: you *can’t* use a function before it’s defined. But, despite appearances to the contrary, this also isn’t happening here.

`d3wordcloud::renderD3wordcloud` is a special function call which doesn’t evaluate its arguments immediately. In fact, the argument is stored internally as an unevaluated expression and is only evaluated *later* after a certain trigger. By that time, `rval_top_ingredients` has been defined.

This is a pervasive pattern in Shiny, but you can harness this behaviour yourself. Consider the following:

```
f = function (expr) {}

f(g())

g = function () { stop('oh no!') }
```

This code works, since `f` never uses its argument, and since R uses [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation) for function arguments: unlike most other languages, a function argument only gets evaluated once it is *used*. Arguments that are never used are never evaluated.

So, despite the fact that `f(g())` appears to use `g` before it’s defined, the actual call to `f` never evaluates its arguments so there’s no issue. The only constraint is that the argument needs to be syntactically valid.

Here’s a slightly more meaningful example which does something useful (it creates a function that creates a log message before evaluating an expression:

```
make_verbose = function (expr) {
    function () {
        message(sprintf('Evaluating %s', deparse(substitute(expr))))
        expr
    }
}

verbose_g = make_verbose(g())

g = function () {
    message('g was called!')
}

verbose_g()
```

Python doesn’t quite support this, since Python doesn’t have lazy and non-standard evaluation. But a similar situation still exists in Python:

```py
def f():
    g()

def g():
    print('g()')

f()
```

Here, `g()` is seemingly used before it was defined; but this is only true if we’re reading the code textually from top top bottom without paying attention to scope. In reality, `g()` is only ever called *after* it was defined. The same is true in the R code you’ve posted.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, Konrad. I now understand why the spinet of code in the OP works. I also understand the logical flow n your third (Python) example: `g()` was defined before it was used in the call of `f()`, so that makes sense. However, I'm not sure I can follow the other 2 examples (as I have very little knowledge in programming), particularly the first one: why doesn't`f(g())` use the argument `g()`? What is the purpose of that line `f(g())`, doesn't it mean to execute `f`?

Comment: @Nemo Ah, my explanation glossed over a crucial property of R. I’ve added a bit more explanation. The reason is that R uses lazy evaluation for arguments. Check out the link I added to the answer.